# How to merge theme settings from 2 different Visual Studio themes?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am using the "Colorful Darkness" theme and I love it!
http://studiostyl.es/schemes/colorful-darkness

The only thing is that it has bad html and razor support. How can I take out the html and razor color/font settings from the below theme and merge it into the "Colorful Darkness" theme to create an all new theme?
http://studiostyl.es/schemes/brian-s-vibrant-ink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to open both setting files in a text editor and do a copy and paste manually. I don't know any other way

Comment: I recently had an issue where the 'theme' that I wanted seemed to be split into to different files. One file contained the Theme colors (i.e. tab, window, icon, frames, etc...) and the other contained the Fonts colors I wanted. I took turns exporting the settings for just the fonts on the one and just the theme settings on the other. Using Notepad++ I was able to merge the two files and save as a new .vssettings. Then Imported the new settings file from Toos/ImportExport... and viola!!!! I now have the theme color settings with the font color settings... its nice....